# How do I use GDAL to convert from an arbitrary projection/datum into Equirectangular/WGS84?

Tags: coordinate-system, raster, gdal, datum

I've been trying to use GDAL to convert from an arbitrary projection/datum into Equirectangular (aka Plate Caree, aka Equidistant Cylindrical, aka Geographic, aka Lat/Long) with WGS84 datum.  All of my input files have an associated PRJ file that I've been using with GDAL with this statement:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs Input.prj -t_srs Output.prj Input.xyz Output.tif
```

So far, I've had mixed results.  I've been able to successfully transform a Lambert Equal Area projection in WGS84 to Geographic/WGS84, but performing a transform on LEA in RT90 projection causes an error of ~1km.

Stranger still, I tried to transform two Sinusoidal projections in RT90 and in WGS84, both of which resulted in an error of 16km!  I suspect that these errors are largely due to some sort of ellipsoid/sphere discrepancy.

I'm very confused as to why these errors are so random, but more concerned that they are happening at all.  Shouldn't `gdalwarp` take any ellipsoid information about the source and target from the PRJ files and transform between them?

What can I do to correct my issue?

Comment: please provide the contents of the Input.prj and the Output.prj for the various cases of success and failure that you report

Comment: This is a cross posting: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2010-November/026929.html

Comment: Its important to remember that resampling and reprojection of rasters is a lossy process, even after you sort out your projection issues.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved my problem.

RT90 is not a defined datum in Proj4.  As such, GDAL just up and ignores the datum entry and applies the ellipsoid and projection correction.

It'd be nice if a warning was thrown at some point ("WARNING: datum 'RT90' not recognized" would be enough, but I digress).

The sinusoidal projection in WGS84 datum was transforming incorrectly because the Sinusoidal projection wasn't being set properly when export from Global Mapper.  When I hand-rolled my own SRS to be "+proj=sinu +datum=WGS84" everything worked out fine.

To get proj4 to list various types of datums/projections/ellipsoids that it supports:

```
proj -ld    //lists known datums
proj -le    //lists known ellipsoids
proj -l     //lists known projections (use -lP for an expanded view)
```

If you want GDAL to work with unknown datum types, you must specify "+towgs84=" in your source SRS, and you must also specify "+towgs84=" in your target SRS if your target datum is not WGS84.  These tags must be followed by 3 or 7 parameter transformation values, which can be found with some google-fu.  More info on this tag can be found here:

http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms#towgs84-DatumtransformationtoWGS84

Hopefully anyone that runs into a similar problem will now be able to do so.

Answer (score 2):

There are many cases where transformation between datums requires more complete information like the parameters for towgs84 - both for input and output -  presumably you have left this out for the transformations that are failing, or you have somehow specified them incorrectly.

Comment: I guess I'm just confused as to why GDAL doesn't have these values baked in.  As per your earlier request, here are the Input and Output files:

Comment: Input.prj (Sinusoidal/RT90):   PROJCS["Sinusoidal",GEOGCS["Geographic Coordinate System",DATUM["RT90",SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528131060786]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Sinusoidal"],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]

Comment: Output.prj (Lat/Long, WGS84): GEOGCS["Geographic Coordinate System",DATUM["WGS84",SPHEROID["WGS84",6378137,298.257223560493]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]